# I want camera to be positioned on the player also x axis should move continuosly by .05f in unity 2d

Tags: unity

I am creating an 2d platformer and I am newbie to Unity; any help will be highly appreciated. I want the camera to be positioned on the player and also the X axis should move continuously by .05f. And if player is not moving or stuck somewhere and if player is behind camera player (because X axis is automatically moving by .05f)  then player should die.

Is it doable? I am using Cinemachine and any script logic will be appreciated.

Comment: [It looks to me like there are plenty of existing tutorials about setting up an auto-scroller camera like this in Unity](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+auto-scroller+camera&ia=web). What have you tried based on your research so far? Did you have any specific trouble following one of these guides?

Comment: @DMGregory♦ Thanks for the time. I was able to find the solution. My mistake was my camera was following player. Now I created a gameobject and added camera follow to this and attached transform position script to it.

Comment: Do you want to post an Answer below detailing the steps of your solution? Or would you rather delete this question if it's no longer needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a gameObject and attached cinemachine to this object
2. Attached script to this , FollowObject is the player

   ```
   public GameObject FollowObject;
   private Rigidbody2D rb;

   private void Start()
   {
       rb = FollowObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
   }

   private void FixedUpdate(){     
       float MoveSpeed = rb.velocity.magnitude > Speed ? rb.velocity.magnitude : Speed;
       transform.position += Vector3.right * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
   }
   ```
3. Player script, if player is not visible by main camera he dies(currently reloading the screen)

   ```
    void Update()
    {
        var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(Camera.main);
        var isvisible = GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, collider2D.bounds);
        if (!isvisible)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Gamestart4");
        }        
    }
   ```

PS: Suggestions for improvement is accepted